# ogr2ogr conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int

Tags: sql-server, ogr2ogr, database

I keep getting this Error 1 when I run the following on some tables

```
ogr2ogr -skipfailures -f "MapInfo File" -lco overwrite=yes -lco launder=no -lco relaxedFieldNameMatch "D:\QG\CREFNO.tab" "MSSQL:Server=zzzz;Database=GIS_Test;Trusted_Connection=True" -sql "SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_AUTH_CREFNO" -a_srs EPSG:28354 -t_srs EPSG:28354 -s_srs EPSG:28354
```

[image]

Is there some switch to include that fixes this?

I see that in the DB you can add a convert switch but is it possible to do this in OGR2OGR? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984110/conversion-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-simple-to-data-type-int

I need to keep the output format as .tab

Comment: Found an answer on dba se - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231726/fix-ogr2ogr-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-to-data-type-int-issue-in/231728#231728 We need to go back to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer on dba se - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231726/fix-ogr2ogr-failed-when-converting-the-varchar-value-to-data-type-int-issue-in/231728#231728 We need to go back to the DB.

In the DB we have to change what values are allowed or mapfieldtypes to change varchar to string rather than int.